# Angular2 data table with ajax calls

Tags: angular, typescript, datatables, angular-services, angular-datatables

before I start using Angular/Angular2 I always use jQuery DataTable with ajax calls because when I divide the data with client-side paginations and get the data in advance it makes my page very slowly, therefore, the best way for me is to divide the data in the server-side and return only the rows that are being shown to the user in the same moment.

I'm working on a CRM right now and i have a Clients table with more than 50,000 rows.

**I wonder, what is the best way to make such a table with Angular2?**

Comment: I would guess that no user would want to scroll through 50,000 rows. So it may make sense to build some type of form for the user to enter search criteria to filter to the desired rows. Then pass that filter information to your back-end server as query parameters. Then the app will perform much better.

Comment: @DeborahK, of course, you are right but this is not what I intent, I'm sorry for being not clear. i already using datatable for angular2 - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable , the issue is that this datatable pull all the data and then divide the data in pagination, i want to select only 10 rows for the server side and when you click on "page 2" i will select the next 10 rows

Comment: Sine you have tagged with angular-datatables, you have already answered your own question.

Comment: i know about angular-datatable but i couldn't make it work with ajax calls, it get all the data in the first place and when you change the page with the pagination it make a client side pagination and not server side

Comment: Ilan Finkel, I also stuck here, have you implemented any solution for this ? If yes, then please post your answer. @davidkonrad can you please give more specification on this. Thanks.

Comment: @herr, here is a remote AJAX example -> http://plnkr.co/edit/oNQfgUBk4JvHLsPqUYhx?p=preview serverside should be no problem, but you will have to follow the instructions on datatables.net carefully, since you will need a backend for your own that do the tasks dataTables oterwise would do clientside, such as filtering. It is really hard to code a short example on that. There is a lot of startup scripts for .NET, java, PHP and python out there.